# $A \subset B$ and $|A|=|B| \rightarrow A=B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hey guys I need to use the following result but I'm not sure it's true

$A \subset B$ and $|A|=|B| \rightarrow A=B$

It makes sense with finite sets but not sure if it works in infinite

I need it for finite sets though

Thanks

Comment: Not true for infinite sets. The even numbers are equinumerous with the integers.

Comment: What about discrete?

Comment: Discrete is a topological property. It is not a synonym for "finite". Every infinite set can be given a topology in which it is discrete.

Comment: 'discrete', as I know it, is a term used for partially ordered sets and topological spaces. by discrete do you mean 'finite'?

Comment: Yes I mean finite sorry!

Comment: Then your result is true, so long as you assume some very weak choice principles. The property you are stating is known as Dedekind-finiteness. That Dedekind-finite implies finite is independent of the axioms of ZF.

Comment: Just to be clear, by $|A|=|B|$, do you mean that there is a bijection between $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is certainly true if $A, B$ are finite sets.

But note, $$\mathbb N\subset \mathbb Q,\;|\mathbb N| = |\mathbb Q|,\;\text{but}\;\mathbb N \neq \mathbb Q$$

Comment: So I can use it without proof?

Comment: You can use it when you explicitly limit yourself to finite sets, but you should first convince yourself that it is true for finite $A, B$!

Answer (score 0):

It is true only for finite sets.

The set is finite if its cardinality is equal to some integer — there exists a bijection.
And the set is Dedekind-finite if it is impossible to create a bijection between the set and its proper subset.

Without the axiom of choise there exists a set which is Dedekind-finite but infinite.
In ZFC, however, Dedekind-finite and finite sets are the same thing, so your property is just a definition of finite set.